# What do these lines of shell script do?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Could someone provide a good explanation of what is happening n this code?

```
find ./ \
  -name "myfile.`date +%Y%m%d`*" \
  -size +10 \
  -exec mv {} ./"myfile.`date +%Y%m%d`.gz" \; \
  2>/dev/null
status=$?
```

Comment: have you read the manual page for find? it describes name (matches names), size (matches sizes), and exec (does things to each match). This seems to take all files that match a name-pattern and size and move-or-rename them into a single file. Since no compression is taking place, the last-matched file is the only one present; the rest will have vanished.

Comment: Also if I am correct, `mv {} ./"myfile.\`date +%Y%m%d\`.gz" ` should have been `gzip {}` ...

Comment: @anishsane Why `gzip` a `.gz` file? One argument would be sufficient.

Comment: my bad, I did not notice the `*` at the end of filename pattern. I have a habit of putting the extension at the end of the find-pattern. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Files under the current directory whose names start with `myfile.${current_date}` (where `${current_date}` is the date in YYYYmmdd form) are having `.gz` added to the end of their names, in a moderately buggy fashion.

To break it down line-by-line:

```
find ./ \                           # find files under the current directory
  -name "myfile.`date +%Y%m%d`*" \  # ...only if their name starts with "myfile."
                                    #    followed by the current date as of when
                                    #    this command is started
  -size +10 \                       # ...and only if they're larger than 10
                                    #    512-byte blocks
  -exec mv {} ./"myfile.`date +%Y%m%d`.gz" \; \
                                    # ...and append ".gz" to their names
  2>/dev/null                       # ...and discard any error messages.

status=$?                           # store the exit status of the previous
                                    # ...command in the variable named "status".
```

By the way, running `date` twice this way means that if this is started next to a midnight boundary, the output files could actually have different dates on them than the input files; that makes this command quite dangerous. Moreover, it doesn't preserve the source directory; to prevent recursion, it would need to add a `-maxdepth 1` argument to `find`.

This is also dangerous as it discards suffixes -- if you had multiple files starting with the `myfile.${date}` prefix, all but one would be silently deleted.

Comment: in a very buggy fashion - the last one wins, and they are relocated to the current working directory in the process (find is recursive)

Comment: Maybe you wanted to add that the files it'd find would exceed 5120 bytes in size.

Comment: `...and only if they're larger than 10 bytes` is __WRONG__.

Comment: @devnull Yes, noticed, was already working on an edit during your last comment (after verifying against the docs).

Comment: @devnull script already dictates you to discard any errors :P

Comment: @idursun Certainly not. It's possible to build correct and robust shell scripts; that most people consider writing in shell an excuse to be careless and sloppy doesn't change that. If you want a longer discussion on that topic, head over to `#bash` in irc.freenode.org.